# Meteor/ReactionCommerce - Error: Cannot find module './browsers'

Tags: meteor

After a `rc pull` and then a `rc up`, `meteor run` gives:

```
Error: Cannot find module './browsers'
```

I'm running in a Google Compute Engine Ubuntu 16:

- Node: 4.2.6
- NPM: 3.10.9
- Reaction: 0.16.1
- Reaction CLI: 0.4.21

`meteor list-platforms` shows:

```
browser                                       
server
```

I thought to maybe remove and add the browser platform back but `meteor remove-platform browser` gives:

```
While removing platforms:
error: browser: cannot remove platform in this version of Meteor
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Not yet. Dusting off a Reaction Commerce project. I feel like I've seen this issue before but couldn't find anyone else with it on Google yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the error comes from the latest version of meteor. I went a little further ahead and asked on the Reaction forum and was able to get it solved:

> Happened on osx as well as debian, after update to meteor 1.4.2

Looks that you have to downgrade the meteor version:

```
meteor update --release METEOR@1.4.1
reaction reset
```

Answer 'Yes' on the delete node_modules.

> Package version are identical for both versions.

[This](https://forums.reactioncommerce.com/t/reaction-error-with-browsers-module/232) is the link to the post on the reaction site.

Comment: Thank you @_Warlord, this works. It also works with the minor patch for this Meteor version at METEOR@1.4.1.3